# Dash Plotly hotkeys

Tags: plotly-dash, hotkeys

I have a DASH app with a number of checkboxes. I wish to setup a hotkey that would make a keyboard shortcut to check some boxes if the user hits a keyboard "command D" for example. I searched everywhere I could, and the only reference I found was to use an "accessKey" (recommended by the Dash creator chriddyp). I haven't found any documentation or examples of how to utilize this. Could anyone give me some pointers?

```
 dcc.Checklist(
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'Asleep', 'value': 'sleep'},
                        {'label': 'Direct Vision', 'value': 'direct'},
                        {'label': 'Blind', 'value': 'blind'},
                        {'label': 'Video Laryngoscope', 'value': 'video'},
                        {'label': 'Flex FiberOptic', 'value': 'fiber'},
                        {'label': 'Laryngoscope', 'value': 'Laryngo'},
                        {'label': 'ET tube', 'value': 'ET'},
                        {'label': 'Oral', 'value': 'Oral'},
                        {'label': 'Nasal', 'value': 'nasal'},
                        {'label': 'cuffed', 'value': 'cuffed'},
                        {'label': 'RAE', 'value': 'rae'},
                        {'label': 'LMA', 'value': 'lma'},
                    ],
                    value=['sleep', 'direct', 'ET', 'nasal', 'cuffed', 'rae', 'Laryngo'],
                    inputStyle={'margin-right':'20px','margin-left':'10px'},
```

Currently, I have set defaults to the checklist, but ideally I would like to have everything unchecked on loading and connected with hotkeys. Thanks

Comment: If you're out of other options, you could extend the `Checklist` Dash core component by creating a custom component (https://github.com/plotly/dash-component-boilerplate) that wraps it and provides the hotkey functionality. Otherwise, you could also post a feature request to the Plotly team for the `Checklist` component to support this.

Comment: Thx, I'll start looking into that